# Using ng-repeat to show json data fetched from database

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have implemented a process to show my data from database in a `#showdata` div with the following method.

```
function UserCntrl($scope) {

getUser();

$scope.save = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UserService.asmx/InsertUser",
        data: "{'Username':'" + $scope.Name + "','Email':'" + $scope.Mail + "','Password':'" + $scope.Password + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
            $("#showdata").append("Username: " + $scope.Name + "<br />" + "Email:" + $scope.Mail + "<br />");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
};

function getUser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UserService.asmx/GetUserDetails",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var parsed = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
                $("#showdata").append("Username: " + jsondata.Name + "<br />" + "Email:" + jsondata.Mail + "<br />");
            });
        },
        error: function (XHR, errStatus, errorThrown) {
            var err = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            errorMessage = err.Message;
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
  };
}
```

Everything working just fine and all data showing properly in `#showdata` div. But now I want to do the same thing but by using the ng-repeat directive.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This looks like very un-Angular code. Can you show your controller/directive/service code?

Comment: If you want to achieve this, start by using Angular.js instead of jQuery.

Comment: I am very new to angularjs, so these things confusing me much. I provided my complete controller code. I hope it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

as RGraham said, it's not the "angular way" to work with HTTP request but as a starting point, here's a working example:

js:

```
function EntryCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rootEntry = [];
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos').success(function(root) {
        $scope.rootEntry = root;
    });
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="EntryCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="root in rootEntry">{{root.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Grlgfob6tjE63JizWdCD?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

$scope.data = object

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
      <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'parsed' is in your controller's $scope property

```
<div id="showdata">
    <div ng-repeat="(i, jsondata) in parsed" >{{"Username: " + jsondata.Name + "<br />" + "Email:" + jsondata.Mail + "<br />"}}</div> 
</div>
```